# Wordpress doesn't accept web.xml mapping? Or Java build classes?

Tags: java, php, wordpress, eclipse, xampp

I am a beginner and self learning web development for my personal interest, and I have a general question.

I developed a Dynamic Web application in eclipse which uses index.php (or .html ; I can choose) to make a call to javascript file, the JS file calls a java servlet for some optimization and internal calculations through AJAX call, and returns back data to JS and later to the HTML form on index.php. All the paths and mappings are done on web.xml file, and everything works perfectly! The project involves some external google libraries as well, which I have included in eclipse through Build Path.

Then I installed Wordpress locally through Xampp and copied all these files (including all the java classes and external JARs) keeping the folder structure same. Here, index.php does make the call to javascript file, but for AJAX call to java it shows me network error 404. So I have 2 questions:

1. Does the Wordpress doesn't accept mapping through web.xml? Should I only use absolute paths? I am avoiding absolute paths since I want flexibility in moving files around and I don't know how it will work online when I upload my project somewhere.
2. Or is the Wordpress/ Xampp not building/ compiling Java classes and external JARs somehow like it is done in Eclipse? I have no idea how this works! I did copy all the updated class files and stuff to the wordpress folders.

Please let me know how to proceed from here, or any suggestions in things I need to learn! I am keen to use Wordpress since it will save me lot of time in writing all the page codes for my website but the java file is also integral to it since it does lot of backend work. I saw lot of comments online that wordpress and java don't go together since it being a PHP based (I actually learned PHP due to this), but it works in eclipse using these 2 languages, so I am hopeful!! So any guidance will be really appreciated!

Thank you! :D

Anang

Comment: To deploy java servlet code, you need a servlet container like Tomcat

Comment: xampp does have tomcat inside it, I am just wondering if it is being applied to this project as well

Comment: just checked- Tomcat is running within xampp!

Comment: Is your java code deployed to Tomcat (as a .war file or exploded war folder)?

Comment: Is that required? I thought xampp or tomcat automatically compiles the project like eclipse. I just copied all the files(including compiled class files) and folders in wordpress directory.
How do I deploy it to wordpress as .war file? Will that include external JAR files also? Please explain me the process or guide me to some link where I can learn this.

Comment: wordpress is just a cms tool and not a server. It runs on a server, which in your case is Apache server (part of XAMPP). You can read a bit more on internet about  deploying java servlets and servlet containers.

Comment: ok thank you, let me look it up :)